# Is there something like .NET Reflector for Qt?

Tags: qt, reflection, refactoring

Once I've seen a nice tool called .NET Reflector. It can show the entire object hierarchy of .Net binaries/apps (sorry if the term is wrong).
Is there something like this for Qt? As Qt has very good QMetaObject abilities, it should be possible to traverse object-trees, call methods(slots), change properties, etc.

I am currently re-factoring a Qt project. The naming of variables is very domain specific and I am not the expert in this domain. So, it is difficult for me to map a widget-variable to the widget on the screen. Such tool would be a great help for me to understand the code.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's QSpy project. It inspects all QWidgets of running application. I'm not sure how well it works, because I couldn't use it on Mac OS X. Maybe on Windows it works better. https://github.com/sashao/martlet
http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QSpy?content=102287

Comment: Thank you. Looks not as mature as .Net Reflector, but beter than nothing, and there is code there!

Answer (score 2):

For simple uses you might want to take a look at [`QObject::dumpObjectTree()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree)

If you need something more advanced there's *[kspy](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/kspy.htm)*

> kspy: examines the internal state of a
>   Qt/KDE app KSpy is a tiny library
>   which can be used to graphically
>   display the QObjects in use by a
>   Qt/KDE app. In addition to the object
>   tree, you can also view the
>   properties, signals and slots of any
>   QObject. Basically it provides much
>   the same info as
>   QObject::dumpObjectTree() and
>   QObject::dumpObjectInfo(), but in a
>   much more convenient form. KSpy has
>   minimal overhead for the application,
>   because the kspy library is loaded
>   dynamically using KLibLoader. See /usr
>   /share/doc/kspy/README for usage
>   instructions. This package is part of
>   the KDE Software Development Kit.

It depends on KDE's klibloader so if you are not under KDE you have to modify it but it should be rather easy. Sources are [here](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/KDE/kdesdk/kspy/).